# How do I use gcloud compute ssh with ssh's -t flag?

Tags: ssh, gcloud, tty

How do I use gcloud compute ssh with ssh's -t flag (pseudo-terminal allocation)?

Comment: What actual problem are you having?

Comment: @Kenster "By default, SUDO is configured to require a TTY. That is, SUDO is expected to be run from a login shell. You can defeat this requirement by adding the -t switch to your SSH invocation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [--ssh-flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#--ssh-flag) to pass the flags to the ssh command.

```sh
gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE --zone=ZONE --ssh-flag="-t"
```